# Best option to split a column into 2, 3, 4, 5 or more columns

Tags: google-sheets, filter, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, modulo

I have this formula to split a column into two columns:

```
=ArrayFormula(
IFERROR(HLOOKUP(1,{1;**COLUMN TO DIVIDE**},
(ROW(A:A)+1)*2-TRANSPOSE(sort(ROW(A1:A2)+0,1,0)))))
```

I would like to know if there is a better way to do this and if there is a way to create one formula that can be used to easily define when I wanted to split one column into two, three, four, five or more columns.

I couldn't create a very concrete way to split into more columns than two. Failures always occur.

Link to spreadsheet:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1iUX01lsfrhq7OSMgSg-QZrWL7wMijqpK03uneQZgP3g/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: share a copy of your sheet pls

Comment: @player0 Question updated mate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe this will fit your needs:

```
={FILTER(A2:A, MOD(ROW(A2:A), 2)=0), FILTER(A2:A, NOT(MOD(ROW(A2:A), 2)=0))}
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Very simple and intuitive the format executed for 3 or more columns, amazing!